# yahoo api county list append to select box

Tags: jquery, json, api, yahoo-api

I am new to API calls. I have to use yahoo geoplanet API. I want to append all country list inside one select box. This is my select list

```
<select id="Country"></select>
```

and this is my id link

```
var country = 'http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/countries?appid=w1u_hHfV34HRdninyHHdnigDEeGV9x4PnbnsKOw4';
```

how should i do?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: I am very new to apis. Can you please give the full detail how should i write my script? @PalashMondal

Comment: Just load the data(xml) from the yahoo api using [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and then parse it using [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and get the `name` from the xml nodes and add it to the option and then append all the options to the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and append **&output=json** to get the data in JSON format.

Then, you can easily parse the returned data as follow:

```
$.getJSON('http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/countries?appid=w1u_hHfV34HRdninyHHdnigDEeGV9x4PnbnsKOw4&output=json', function (data) {
        for(var i in data.places.place){
            $('#Country').append('<option value="'+data.places.place[i]['woeid']+'">'+data.places.place[i]['name']+'</option>')
        }
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RwZRq/)